# How can I write to the flash memory of a PIC24FJ?

Tags: microcontroller

I am using a PIC microcontroller, exactly the PIC24FJ128GL305 and I want to save important data in flash memory using MPLAB X IDE V6, one of the data I want to save is -733.5847 and I can't save it, in fact I can't even save integers.

Could anyone help me with a library to do what I want, please?

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole lot you will need to learn before this example will make any sense.

This code does work but it is not even close to what you will actually need to create.

Perhaps you will learn enough from a working example to be able to ask a better question.

```
/*
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: dan1138
 *
 * Description:
 *  Example for Run Time Self Programming (RTSP).
 *  This is very limited, useful as a test bench but not much more.
 *
 * Created on December 14, 2022, 9:07 PM
 */

/* Define the system oscillator frequency this code must configure */
#define FSYS (8000000ul)
#define FCY  (FSYS/2ul)

// PIC24FJ128GL305 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// FSEC
#pragma config BWRP = OFF               // Boot Segment Write-Protect bit (Boot Segment may be written)
#pragma config BSS = DISABLED           // Boot Segment Code-Protect Level bits (No Protection (other than BWRP))
#pragma config BSEN = OFF               // Boot Segment Control bit (No Boot Segment)
#pragma config GWRP = OFF               // General Segment Write-Protect bit (General Segment may be written)
#pragma config GSS = DISABLED           // General Segment Code-Protect Level bits (No Protection (other than GWRP))
#pragma config CWRP = OFF               // Configuration Segment Write-Protect bit (Configuration Segment may be written)
#pragma config CSS = DISABLED           // Configuration Segment Code-Protect Level bits (No Protection (other than CWRP))
#pragma config AIVTDIS = OFF            // Alternate Interrupt Vector Table bit (Disabled AIVT)

// FBSLIM
#pragma config BSLIM = 0x1FFF           // Boot Segment Flash Page Address Limit bits (Enter Hexadecimal value)

// FOSCSEL
#pragma config FNOSC = FRC              // Oscillator Source Selection (Internal Fast RC (FRC))
#pragma config PLLMODE = DISABLED       // PLL Mode Selection (No PLL used; PLLEN bit is not available)
#pragma config IESO = ON                // Two-speed Oscillator Start-up Enable bit (Start up device with FRC, then switch to user-selected oscillator source)

// FOSC
#pragma config POSCMD = NONE            // Primary Oscillator Mode Select bits (Primary Oscillator disabled)
#pragma config OSCIOFCN = ON            // OSC2 Pin Function bit (OSC2 is general purpose digital I/O pin)
#pragma config SOSCSEL = ON             // SOSC Power Selection Configuration bits (SOSC is used in crystal (SOSCI/SOSCO) mode)
#pragma config PLLSS = PLL_PRI          // PLL Secondary Selection Configuration bit (PLL is fed by the Primary oscillator)
#pragma config IOL1WAY = OFF            // Peripheral pin select configuration bit (Allow multiple reconfigurations)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSECMD           // Clock Switching Mode bits (Clock switching is enabled,Fail-safe Clock Monitor is disabled)

// FWDT
#pragma config WDTPS = PS32768          // Watchdog Timer Postscaler bits (1:32,768)
#pragma config FWPSA = PR128            // Watchdog Timer Prescaler bit (1:128)
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Enable bits (WDT and SWDTEN disabled)
#pragma config WINDIS = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Window Enable bit (Watchdog Timer in Non-Window mode)
#pragma config WDTWIN = WIN25           // Watchdog Timer Window Select bits (WDT Window is 25% of WDT period)
#pragma config WDTCMX = WDTCLK          // WDT MUX Source Select bits (WDT clock source is determined by the WDTCLK Configuration bits)
#pragma config WDTCLK = LPRC            // WDT Clock Source Select bits (WDT uses LPRC)

// FPOR
#pragma config BOREN = OFF              // Brown Out Enable bit (Brown Out Disabled)
#pragma config LPCFG = OFF              // Low power regulator control (No Retention Sleep)
#pragma config DNVPEN = ENABLE          // Downside Voltage Protection Enable bit (Downside protection enabled using ZPBOR when BOR is inactive)

// FICD
#pragma config ICS = PGD1               // ICD Communication Channel Select bits (Communicate on PGEC1 and PGED1)
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF             // JTAG Enable bit (JTAG is disabled)

// FDMTIVTL
#pragma config DMTIVTL = 0xFFFF         // Deadman Timer Interval Low Word (Enter Hexadecimal value)

// FDMTIVTH
#pragma config DMTIVTH = 0xFFFF         // Deadman Timer Interval High Word (Enter Hexadecimal value)

// FDMTCNTL
#pragma config DMTCNTL = 0xFFFF         // Deadman Timer Instruction Count Low Word (Enter Hexadecimal value)

// FDMTCNTH
#pragma config DMTCNTH = 0xFFFF         // Deadman Timer Instruction Count High Word (Enter Hexadecimal value)

// FMDT
#pragma config DMTDIS = OFF             // Deadman Timer Enable Bit (Dead Man Timer is Disabled and can be enabled by software)

// FDEVOPT1
#pragma config ALTCMPI = DISABLE        // Alternate Comparator Input Enable bit (C2INC and C3INC are on their standard pin locations )
#pragma config TMPRPIN = OFF            // Tamper Pin Enable bit (TMPRN pin function is disabled)
#pragma config SOSCHP = ON              // SOSC High Power Enable bit (valid only when SOSCSEL = 1 (Enable SOSC high power mode (default))
#pragma config ALTI2C1 = ALTI2C1_OFF    // Alternate I2C pin Location (I2C1 Pin mapped to SDA1/SCL1 pins)
#pragma config SMB3EN = SMBUS3          // SM Bus Enable (SMBus 3.0 input levels)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
#include <libpic30.h>

#define MEMORY_USER_CALIBRATION_LOC (_FLASH_PAGE * 24)

typedef struct
{
    float fCal;
} stFlashStruct_t;

volatile const __prog__ __attribute__((space(prog), address(MEMORY_USER_CALIBRATION_LOC))) union 
{
    uint16_t words[_FLASH_PAGE];    /* reserve the entire erase page. Note only the low 16-bits of the instruction word can be accessed with this method. */
    struct {
        stFlashStruct_t stFlashStruct;  /* calibration structure */
    };
} CalSpace =
{   
    .stFlashStruct.fCal = 1.0,
};

int main(void) 
{
    volatile stFlashStruct_t ReadBack;
    
    /*
     * application initialization
     */
    ReadBack.fCal = CalSpace.stFlashStruct.fCal;
    __builtin_software_breakpoint();  /* breakpoint here to inspect the ReadBack structure with the debugger */
    Nop();
    Nop();
    
    /* Erase 1024 instruction words starting at address MEMORY_USER_CALIBRATION_LOC */
    NVMCON = 0x4003;
    NVMADR = __builtin_tbloffset(&CalSpace);
    NVMADRU = __builtin_tblpage(&CalSpace);
    __builtin_disi(5);                          // Disable interrupts for NVM unlock
    __builtin_write_NVM();                      // Start write cycle
    while(NVMCONbits.WR == 1);    

    ReadBack.fCal = CalSpace.stFlashStruct.fCal;
    __builtin_software_breakpoint();  /* breakpoint here to inspect the ReadBack structure with the debugger */
    Nop();
    Nop();
    
    /* Update data in structure to be written */
    ReadBack.fCal = -733.5847;

    /* Write 2 instruction words starting at address MEMORY_USER_CALIBRATION_LOC */
    NVMCON = 0x4001; // Set WREN and word program mode
    TBLPAG = 0xFA; // write latch upper address
    NVMADR = __builtin_tbloffset(&CalSpace.stFlashStruct);
    NVMADRU = __builtin_tblpage(&CalSpace);
    __builtin_tblwtl(0,*((uint16_t *)(&ReadBack)+0));   // load low 16-bits of first instruction word
    __builtin_tblwth(0,0x00);                           // make high 8-bits of first instruction word zero
    __builtin_tblwtl(2,*((uint16_t *)(&ReadBack)+1));   // load low 16-bits of second instruction word
    __builtin_tblwth(2,0x00);                           // make high 8-bits of second instruction word zero
    __builtin_disi(5); // Disable interrupts for NVM unlock sequence
    __builtin_write_NVM(); // initiate write
    while(NVMCONbits.WR == 1);
    
    ReadBack.fCal = CalSpace.stFlashStruct.fCal;
    __builtin_software_breakpoint();  /* breakpoint here to inspect the ReadBack structure with the debugger */
    Nop();
    Nop();

    /*
     * Application process loop
     */
    for(;;)
    {
        Nop();
        Nop();
        Nop();
        __delay_ms(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have given me a good example, I saw that you do it as indicated in the manufacturer's data sheet but it is very confusing for me :P , you are right I have a lot to learn, even though I managed to save data in the flash using another code I will try to understand how the yours, thanks for the answer